# Does Gmail API email.send require API Key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail-api

I using Gmail API to send emails to some users, and I am currently attaching the API Key as a parameter to my request. But it seems like when I remove that parameter, the API call still works and the email is still sent. I am wondering if this behavior is expect or does Gmail API not require an API key for sending emails. Thanks

Comment: Gmail requires authorization - it is not optional. Show the code you are using.

Comment: To clarify, I am using the user's access token still, but it seems like to send an email on their behalf, I don't need to include a Google API Key in my request parameters anymore.